# On sefer Job 2:9 "ברך אלהים"

Tags: tanach, job-iyov-book-of

In the sefer of [Job 2:9](https://www.sefaria.org/Job.2.9?lang=bi&with=Midrash%20Tanchuma&lang2=en) it is written:

> "וַתֹּאמֶר לוֹ אִשְׁתּוֹ עֹֽדְךָ מַֽחֲזִיק בְּתֻמָּתֶךָ בָּרֵךְ אֱלֹהִים וָמֻֽת׃"

Why **"ברך אלהים"** is translated as Curse G-d and not as Bless G-d as is the normal translation?

Comment: http://allfaith.com/noahide/birchathashem.html

Comment: I see, "barech elokim" is an understatement to insulting G‑d

Answer (score 3):

Firstly because using such euphemisms is common in Torah literature and Birchas Hashem is the standard reference to doing the opposite.

In the peskukim before  this one Birchas Hashem is  used twice to clearly mean the oppisite. The Soton says to Hashem that if Iyov will have difficulty he will "bless" you. And when Iyov's children died he said Maybe they "blessed" Hashem in their hearts.

Also what would be the cause of his imminent death  if he were to bless God?

Answer (score 3):

The [Malbim](https://www.sefaria.org/Job.2.9?lang=bi&p2=Malbim_on_Job.2.9.1&lang2=bi) notes that Iyov's wife is taunting him, and that the term "ברך אלהים" is in effect goading Iyov to try and bless G-d again, with his wife assuming that it will again result in the reverse. So, whilst it does still mean "bless", it is being used as means to deride Iyov.

> עודך מחזיק בתמתך, כי בפעם הראשון ברך על הרעה כמ"ש יהי שם ה' מבורך, ובפעם הזה לא ברך ה' רק שתק, כי בלבבו לא היה שלם בפעם הזאת כמו שית', **ואמרה לו אשתו להקניטו** הנה בפעם הראשון שברכת את ה' על הרעה שבזה הראית שאתה תמים עמו הוסיף להכותך גם בגופך, ואם עתה תברך שנית הלא בהכרח יוסיף להכותך בנפש עד שתמות, כי אין לו להכות אותך עוד בדבר אחר, וא"כ אחר שעודך מחזיק בתומתך למה אתה שותק זאת הפעם ואינך מברך על הרעה, ברך אלהים גם עתה ותמות, והיא הקנטה הלציית על שברך בפעם הראשון

Alternatively, the [Midrash Tanchuma on Yisro 16:5](https://www.sefaria.org/Midrash_Tanchuma%2C_Yitro.16.5?lang=bi) makes an interesting observation:

> **וּכְשֶׁהַפֻּרְעָנוּת בָּאָה עֲלֵיהֶן מְקַלְּלִין לְיִרְאוֹתֵיהֶן** שֶׁנֶּאֱמַר (ישעיה ח, כא): וְהָיָה כִי יִרְעַב וְהִתְקַצַּף וְקִלֵּל בְּמַלְכּוֹ וּבֵאלֹהָיו וּפָנָה לְמָעְלָה (ישעיה ח, כא). אֲבָל אַתֶּם תִּהְיוּ נוֹתְנִים הוֹדָיָה עַל הַטּוֹבָה וְעַל הָרָעָה. שֶׁכֵּן דָּוִד אוֹמֵר: כּוֹס יְשׁוּעוֹת אֶשָּׂא וּבְשֵׁם ה' אֶקְרָא (תהלים קטז, יג). צָרָה וְיָגוֹן אֶמְצָא, וּבְשֵׁם ה' אֶקְרָא (תהלים קטז, ג-ד). וְכֵן אִיּוֹב אוֹמֵר: ה' נָתַן וַה' לָקָח יְהִי שֵׁם ה' מְבֹרָךְ (איוב א, כא), עַל מִדָּה טוֹבָה וְעַל מִדַּת פֻּרְעָנוּת. **מָה אִשְׁתּוֹ אוֹמֶרֶת לוֹ, עֹדְךָ מַחֲזִיק בְּתֻמָּתְךָ בָּרֵךְ אֱלֹהִים וָמֻת** (תהלים ב, ט). אָמַר לָהּ: כְּדַבֵּר אַחַת הַנְּבָלוֹת תְּדַבֵּרִי גַּם אֶת הַטּוֹב נְקַבֵּל מֵאֵת הָאֱלֹהִים וְאֶת הָרָע לֹא נְקַבֵּל (תהלים ב, י) וְצָרִיךְ אָדָם לִהְיוֹת שָׂמֵחַ בַּיִּסּוּרִין יוֹתֵר מִן הַטּוֹבָה. שֶׁאֲפִלּוּ אָדָם בְּטוֹבָה כָּל יָמָיו, לֹא נִמְחָל לוֹ עֲבֵרוֹת שֶׁבְּיָדוֹ. וּבַמֶּה נִמְחָל לוֹ, בְּיִסּוּרִין.
>
> **However, when afflictions befall them, they curse those they fear**, as it is said: And it shall come to pass that, when they shall be hungry, they shall fret themselves, and curse by their king and by their god (Isa. 8:21). However, you shall praise Me both for fortune and for misfortune. Thus David said: I will fill up the cup of salvation, and call upon the name of the Lord (Ps. 116:13), whether for good or for evil. **Then said his wife unto him: “Dost thou still hold fast thine integrity? Blaspheme God, and die!”** But he said unto her: “Thou speakest as one of the impious women speaketh. What? Shall we receive good at the hand of God, and shall we not receive evil?” (Job. 2:9–10). A man should rejoice over his afflictions more than over his good fortune. Even if man should enjoy good fortune all his life, (this merely indicates that) the sins he committed are not being forgiven. What causes sins to be forgiven? Only suffering. (Sefaria translation)

So according to the Tanchuma it is a human reaction to curse those that one normally fears when facing hardships and the like, and as such, this is the reason why in this context it is used differently.

Comment: Thanks for the answer

Comment: Pleasure! If you feel it answers your question feel free to click the checkmark.